# php - do something on soap empty response or not found

Tags: php, if-statement, soap, response

I need to do some search on a WS, I have it working, but I need to be able to know when the soap can not find anything with the word I'm looking.

For example, when I search for KE-5977 I get a response and all the data

```
<GetChoferesResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/asdf.DTO" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <a:Choferes>
      <a:ChoferesDTO>
         <a:dc_patente>KE-5977</a:dc_patente>
         <a:dc_patente_habitual>KE-5977</a:dc_patente_habitual>
         <a:dc_rut_chofer>10165014-6</a:dc_rut_chofer>
         <a:dc_tipo_equipo>4</a:dc_tipo_equipo>
         <a:dc_tipo_transportista>E</a:dc_tipo_transportista>
         <a:dg_nombre_chofer>JUAN SOTO</a:dg_nombre_chofer>
         <a:dg_tipo_de_equipo>Camión</a:dg_tipo_de_equipo>
         <a:dg_tipo_transportista>Externo (Se llama a transporte ocasionalmente)</a:dg_tipo_transportista>
         <a:dn_ano_fabricacion>1988</a:dn_ano_fabricacion>
         <a:dq_capacidad_equipo>30.0000</a:dq_capacidad_equipo>
      </a:ChoferesDTO>
   </a:Choferes>
</GetChoferesResult>
```

but if I put it wrong like this "KE-7759" I get nothing.

```
<GetChoferesResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/asdf.DTO" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:Choferes/>
         </GetChoferesResult>
      </GetChoferesResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I need to show a message "code not found" when I get an empty response from soap (soap request did not found anything with that code).

Please help me.

Update:

This is taken from SoapUI:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy4lc.jpg

In PHP I do it like this:

I ask if $isarray is array just because the response from soap can have multiple responses, to get the values when i get multiple responses i have to ask for "$response->GetChoferesResult->Choferes->ChoferesDTO", if i get only one response, the values are in "$response->GetChoferesResult->Choferes".

```
$response = $sClient->GetChoferes(array("req"=>array("PatenteHabitual"=>$patente)));


    $isarray = $response->GetChoferesResult->Choferes->ChoferesDTO;
    $xml = $response->GetChoferesResult->Choferes;
    if (is_array($isarray)){
        foreach($xml as $chofer){

            foreach($chofer as $chofer2){
                $rut=$chofer2->dc_rut_chofer;
                $nombre=$chofer2->dg_nombre_chofer;
                ?><option value="<?php echo strtoupper($rut); ?>"     selected="selected"><?php echo strtoupper($nombre); ?></option><?php


            }

        }
    }else{
        foreach($xml as $chofer){
            if($chofer->dc_patente && $chofer->dg_nombre_chofer && $chofer->dc_patente_habitual){
                $rut=$chofer->dc_rut_chofer;
                $nombre=$chofer->dg_nombre_chofer;

                ?><option value="<?php echo strtoupper($rut); ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo strtoupper($nombre); ?></option><?php


            }else{
                ?><option value="" selected="selected">Patente no encontrada</option><?php

            }
        }
    }
```

Also, i would like to know if i can order the responses by a value, in this case by dg_nombre_chofer (by name).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strpos($response, '<a:Choferes/>')`
http://php.net/strpos

I use simplexml and convert the object to array using:

```
    function objectsIntoArray($arrObjData, $arrSkipIndices = array()){
    $arrData = array();

    // if input is object, convert into array
    if (is_object($arrObjData)) {
        $arrObjData = get_object_vars($arrObjData);
    }

    if (is_array($arrObjData)) {
        foreach ($arrObjData as $index => $value) {
            if (is_object($value) || is_array($value)) {
                $value = objectsIntoArray($value, $arrSkipIndices); // recursive call
            }
            if (in_array($index, $arrSkipIndices)) {
                continue;
            }
            $arrData[$index] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $arrData;
}

    $process = $response->RetrieveListingDataResult;
    $process = utf8_encode($process);
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.$process;
    $xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $arrXml = objectsIntoArray($xmlObj);
```

Comment: if i do a print_r of the request i get this

    stdClass Object
(
    [Choferes] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

)
and <a:Choferes/> is in both cases

Comment: How are you building your query and processing your response?

Comment: $response = $sClient->GetChoferes(array("req"=>array("PatenteHabitual"=>$patente)));

Comment: danc403, i just updates my question and added more info. Thanks

Comment: Try if `(is_array($isarray) && !empty($isarray))`
also you can use one of the many sort options eg. `asort($isarray)`;
http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: The problem is that only when i get more than 1 response, $isarray is an array, if i get only one response (like if i seach for a specific code) $isarray doesnt exist, so its not an array and i have to use the other $xml to get the data and that one is not an array, its an object,  `$isarray = $response->GetChoferesResult->Choferes->ChoferesDTO;` `$xml = $response->GetChoferesResult->Choferes;`. If i dont get anything, $isarray is not an array, $xml is an object with nothing in it, empty, ==null or =="" doesnt work.